# How do I resolve a Django database conflict

Tags: django, database

Can't figure what's wrong??

> settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. "
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.
> [30/Jun/2021 17:31:00] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 194335

Comment: Can you share your db configration in settings.py

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not passing the name of the database in DATABASES configuration in settings.py. Ideal settings would be like this if you're using MySQL:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'name_of_the_database',
        'USER': 'name_of_the_user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password_of_the_user',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
}
```

Feel free to change the ENGINE value if you're using other database server.